# Cannot take the address of an rvalue ObjC

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a ClassA defined as followed

```
@interface ClassA : NSObject
@property (assign) size_t Variable;
@end
```

In ClassB I tried to get the address of ClassA's Variable

```
ClassA *m_ClassA;
void* ptr = &[m_ClassA Variable];
```

But got the following error message
Cannot take the address of an rvalue of type 'size_t'

I know the following code will work but wonder why the error above comes out

```
size_t so = [m_ClassA Variable];
void* ptr = &so;
```

Thank you for precious time on my question.

Comment: Closely related: [Get an address of an ObjC property which is a C struct](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1102018), [C address of an address of a variable](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9976586)

Comment: Thank you so much, Josh Caswell!

Comment: Sure; did one of those answer your question?

Comment: Yes, the first one answers my question